# Find object by comparing two array

Tags: swift, for-loop, where-clause

I have two array, which has the same model.

I'm trying to find the object where it has the same id. I have tried this method which I can find it but **how I can make it without for loop?**

```
    for item in userList {

        let userSelection = user.list.first(where: {$0.id == item.id})
        item.approved = userSelection.approved

        print(userSelection)
    }
```

Comment: Are you trying to find all the items in `userList` that are also contained in `user.list`?

Comment: @IgorKulman Yes that what I am trying to reach.

Comment: @CAN the code you gave posted would get only the first occurrence. please update your question and clarify

Comment: @LeoDabus I have updated my question

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
let userSelection = user.list.filter({userList.map({$0.id}).contains({$0.id})})
```

Explanation:

```
//get all the ids from one list
let ids = userList.map({$0.id})

//filter the second list by including all the users whose id is in the first list
let userSelection = user.list.filter({ids.contains({$0.id})})
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but I am getting this issue:

Cannot call the value of non-function type 'User'

Comment: I split it into 2 parts and described the general idea. Maybe you will have to make som adjustmens on your classes, the idea is important.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about performance, you can use `set.intersection`:

```
let set1:Set<UserType> = Set(userList)
let set2:Set<UserType> = Set(user.list)
let commonItems = set1.intersection(set2)// Intersection of two sets
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if your model is not Hashable, you can use sets to perform the validation:

```
if Set(userList.map{$0.id}).subtracting(user.list.map{$0.id}).count == 0
{
  // all entries in userList exist in user.list
}
else
{
  // at least one entry of userList is not in user.list
}
```